# iphone Ipad application UI development strategy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I am beginner and plan to make a Iphone/Ipad application which will receive a questionary xml from restful webservice, parse it, get answers from user..with two buttons(next, back) on screen, as you may guess there will be validation alert messages, display messages..etc..checkboxes, radiobuttons, date pickers depend on questions type.

So what would be the best strategy, to insert if else blocks on user interface and choose the layout for device type while I am developing the application, or first make a working iphone version and convert it to Ipad later on, and would that be easier? what kind of problems should I expect while converting to IPAD..thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating an universal project with XCode? I think it will give you some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a universal app, you have the option to keep all viewControllers and xib files separate for iPhone and iPad. This is very handy. Alternately, you can check which device the user has and load the correct xib that way, but since the structure of the apps may be quite different, I strongly encourage the latter approach instead.

The ipad has a bigger screen. This is numerous consequences for designing most apps. Also, the ipad has a splitviewcontroller which is quite handy, whereas the iphone tabbarcontroller is better there.

Comment: Tnx, but I am bit confused, so you advise me to keep my viewControllers and xib files sepearete(i dont know what does this means anyway) and load the relevent xib depending on device?

Comment: Really? A tabbar instead of a splitview? Those are not for the same purpose at all!

Comment: @Jongsma: I didn't mean to suggest that they were. I was pointing out that ipad has a feature not available on iphone, and iphone has a feature not often used on ipad.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone and iPad have different UI requirements. Read the apple iOS human interface guidelines, it's very nicely explained in there. You'll also find the answer of what to do if you usually would use radio buttons, because there are no radio buttons on iOS.